# How to display index entries on the same line as the text being indexed

Tags: margins, indexing

Is it possible to let `showidx` display index entries on the same line as the text being indexed? It seems not as `makeindx.pdf` says:

> This macro actually typesets the *box* containing all the index entries on the current page [...].

Which is a bit ironical since, in `makeindx.pdf` itself, the name of the macro being thereby described, `\@mkidx`, is in the margin, just in front of the text. (Of course, the environment seems different and `\@mkidx` is probably not an index entry. On the other hand, the text in `cleveref.pdf`, which also has margin entries, seems to be just ... text.)

So, given that I am already using `hyperref`, `cleveref` and `tcolorbox`, what might be an answer? Hopefully one that does not require yet *another* package.

Here is a rather long but minimal example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk  
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx 
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
    % rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx 

    \usepackage{cleveref}

        \newcounter{proc}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}

%Begin the Sharpe (2013-01-18) code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1) to have math in Showindex     
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
\newcommand{\INDEX}[1]{\index{#1}}
%End the Sharpe (2013-01-18) code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1) to have math in Showindex               

\makeindex
\begin{document}    

Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. \textbf{Oberdieck}\INDEX{Oberdieck}
Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. 

\newpage

Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed.
\textbf{$\cup$}\INDEX{$\cup$}
Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. Some text necessary to drown the words to be indexed. 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a compilable example?

Comment: I hadn't realized one was needed in this case. I will make one.

Comment: Untested: Try the `imakeidx` package and load `showidx` before

Comment: The above code is the only that works. The hack that loads `showidx` is by the Great Master himself in person. That is why I am not exactly hopeful. But I just realized I had missed the "i" in front of `imakeidx`. I will experiment.

Comment: Looked at `imakeidx` and `reledmac`. Didn't see anything relevant to this issue.